# Binding in skiasharp xamarin forms

Tags: c#, binding, xamarin.forms, skiasharp

I want to bind skpaint color property , since skiasharp forms library doesn't have binding built in. Can somebody show how to achieve this or at least point me in a direction.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to AlexP from xamarin forums i can add my own bindable properties to any controls , its pretty easy

```
 public class BindableSKCanvasView : SKCanvasView
    {

        public static readonly BindableProperty ColorProperty =
                BindableProperty.Create("Color", typeof(SKColor), typeof(BindableSKCanvasView),defaultValue:SKColors.Black, defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay, propertyChanged: RedrawCanvas);

        public SKColor Color
        {
            get => (SKColor)GetValue(ColorProperty);
            set => SetValue(ColorProperty, value);
        }


        private static void RedrawCanvas(BindableObject bindable, object oldvalue, object newvalue)
        {
            BindableSKCanvasView bindableCanvas = bindable as BindableSKCanvasView;
        bindableCanvas.InvalidateSurface();
        }
    }
```

here is the forum link for reference

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/122312/binding-in-skiasharp-xamarin-forms